# SQL Request with Term Research

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm currently working on a search bar which return every Car Brand and Car Model combined according to what the user write into a textbox (Autocomplete function of jQuery)

I tried different things but, doesn't find what I need.

**Here's my request (Not working) :**

```
SELECT carBrand_lib, carModel_lib FROM Model AS mo 
INNER JOIN Brand AS br ON br.carBrand_ID = mo.carBrand_ID 
GROUP BY carBrand_lib, carModel_lib 
HAVING (carBrand_lib + carModel_lib) 
LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' 
ORDER BY carModel_lib ASC LIMIT 10
```

**I did another request which working, but only with the Car Brand or the Model separated but don't find for the two combined.**

```
SELECT carBrand_lib, carModel_lib FROM Model AS mo 
INNER JOIN Brand AS br ON br.carBrand_ID = mo.carBrand_ID 
WHERE carModel_lib LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' OR carBrand_lib 
LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' 
ORDER BY carModel_lib ASC LIMIT 10
```

**An example of what I need :**

If the user search "Porsche 9" for example, it will return from the database : "Porsche 911" or something else containing "Porsche 9", in a list.

With "GT" as research, the database will return "Ford GT", "Nissan GTR"...

---

How can I make my SQL request to research in two columns combined at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved ! I simply used the "CONCAT()" function.

```
SELECT carBrand_lib, carModel_lib FROM Model AS mo 
INNER JOIN Brand AS br ON br.carBrand_ID = mo.carBrand_ID 
WHERE CONCAT(carBrand_lib, ' ', carModel_lib ) 
LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' 
ORDER BY carModel_lib ASC LIMIT 10
```